# Как настроить локальный сервер с Ubuntu на MacOSX Parallels?

Tags: ubuntu, macos

Хочу работать с привычным сервером и ос локально.
При всем том хочу открывать локальный сайт из браузера в macOS который отдавался бы сервером (Ubuntu) бегущим на виртуальный машине paralells. Или VirtualBox, приветствую оба варианта. Как это все настроить?

Answer (score 1):

1. Заходите в виртуальную машину, смотрите в ней IP-адрес (`ifconfig`)
2. вбиваете его на маке в браузер (`http://.../`).

Чтобы было удобнее, можно настроить статический адрес в виртуальной машине и сделать для него синоним в `/etc/hosts` на маке, тогда можно будет ходить по `http://ubuntu-server/`: http://manski.net/2011/12/assign-dns-name-to-virtual-machine-here-parallels-desktop-7/